# WordPress .htaccess rewrite to a plugin directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I needed to rewrite the url of 
site.com/plugin-page/1234
to 
site.com/wp-content/plugins/the-plugin/packages/1234

but for some reason the url redirects instead of just rewriting. I needed it just to rewrite, not redirect.

Here's my .htaccess code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^index/.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

    RewriteRule ^plugin-page/?(.*)$ /wp-content/plugins/the-plugin/packages/$1/index.html [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your rule is very important, try it this way:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^plugin-page/([0-9]+)/?$ /wp-content/plugins/the-plugin/packages/$1/index.html [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^index/.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

What was most likely happening is that due to your rule being last WP was trying to find it by itself within its code, resulting on a redirect instead of a internal redirect.

Also make sure that `index.html` and the path you're internally redirecting to, exist.

Comment: @Jronny well unhappily my crystal ball is not working today, would you mind describing what `it did not work` means? Does it give you a 404? WP does anything? Be as descriptive as possible or I won't be able to help you at all. **Also make sure that index.html and the path you're internally redirecting to, exist in your FTP.**

Comment: Still the same, redirecting instead of rewriting. The path exists.

Comment: @Jronny do you have a `.htaccess` in any other **folder within the path** you're trying to redirect to? Where its redirecting it to, to the folder or else where?

Comment: Nope, only one .htaccess file.

Comment: @Jronny well I am afraid your issue is else where then. The rule seems just fine to me. Try accessing it using a different browser you haven't used it to make sure you're not cached from previous attempts or use of 301 since it was redirecting. Manually access that address and make sure you can access the index.html directly. [**You said its a WordPress plugin, if it is then you should use WordPress redirect API for the plugin rather than mod_rewrite.**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67184/discussion-between-jronny-and-prix).

Comment: Weird, it could have been my cache, but when I opened the link to another browser it finally works! Thanks man.

Comment: @Jronny no problem, if you had previously tried the rule with for example R or R=301 that did make a permanent redirect which would have cached the browser being used and by using a different browser you can instantly see if it was cached or not as sometimes it takes time for the other browser to clear its cached data even after you clear it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I actually tried R=301 as I was out of luck earlier. Wouldn't do that anymore. lol. Thanks.

Comment: @Jronny when you do, always use 302 first, as it will redirect but not cache you, once you have confirmed it is working as it needs to then you can switch to either 301 or other method depending on what you need it to do.

Comment: @Prix: nothing to do with this thread - but I just found that you have the highest proportion of accepted answers of all SO users with more than 100 answers (http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1433/users-with-highest-accept-rate-of-their-answers) - very impressive, congrats! You're welcome to share your secret :)